# Get the count or sum of count of each individual items used in multi-select dropdown in google sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, google-spreadsheets

I have created a multi-select drop-down of items a,b,c, & d. Let's say I enter a,b in C1 and a,b,c in C2 and a,b,c,d in C3. Now, I want to get the total count of each item I have selected. Here, we know I have selected "a" thrice i.e (once in C1, once in C2 & once in C3). Similarly, I have selected "b" thrice as well. "c" twice (once in C2, once in C3) and "d" once (in C3). Can anyone suggest a workaround for this? Either in pivot or through a formula.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I create a simple sample as following.

[image]

Then try `=LEN($B$1&$C$1&$D$1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B$1&$C$1&$D$1,E2,""))`.

[image]

If your program names are more than one character, then you need to modify the formula to `=(LEN($B$1&$C$1&$D$1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B$1&$C$1&$D$1,E2,"")))/LEN(E2)`.